# Order array of points in counter clockwise

Tags: 2d, algorithm

I happened to see an answer to "[Sort array of points in clockwise](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/13232/20)", could you please elaborate the 4th point of that answer:

- sort points relative to their a value, using qsort for instance.

How do I do the above step?

I'm looking for an algorithm to sort list of points in counter-clockwise.

Comment: Could you add a link to what answer you're referring to?

Comment: I guess points are two dimensional data. So you could calculate angle between center and point. And since angle is one dimensional data now you can sort it using qsort.

Comment: Sorting requires comparison (<, ==, >), its not obvious how to compare two dimensional data, that's why I suggest you to get angles between point centre and x or y axis.

Comment: It seems that you are just asking how to sort an array of objects. It is not really gamedev-related.

Comment: @SamHocevar  sorting primitives is crucial in developing anything that deals with large multidimensional datasets - especially games.

Comment: @DavidLively See the end of the [first FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq): “Would a professional game developer give me a better/different/more specific answer to this question than other programmers?”. Definitely not. OP is asking about how to use `qsort`.

Comment: @SamHocevar OP is asking how to sort 2D data in a very specific way, typically used to generate an enclosing polygon, which is game-related. Qsort has nothing to do with his question, which is how to determine a useful sort key for points. The same question could be presented in the context of collision detection or draw order. It's relevant to lots of areas.

Comment: Also, things like octrees and matrix manipulation are hardly game-specific, but we don't exclude those questions.

Comment: @DavidLively so we have a question [about ordering points clockwise](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/13232/20) and you are really arguing that ordering points **anti-clockwise** is a question worth asking? Seriously…

Comment: Considering they the site search sucks? Yeah. And the "Possible Duplicate" button is there for a reason.

Comment: @DavidLively Are your objections for real? The *first sentence* of the question has a *direct link*. (And I already voted to close)

Comment: @SamHocevar okay, excellent point. I could argue that the accepted answer is written like an engineering textbook and therefore nearly useless (I have WAY too much experience reading crappily-written papers and books by mathematicians and physicists pretending to be coders), the impenetrability of which spawned this thread) but the actual content is right. Still, I think "that answer doesn't make sense to me" is a valid cry for help. And, isn't that why sites like this exist? Maybe wf should have an "addendum: respectfully, WTF!?" vote option.

Comment: not to go all *ad hominem*, but I have 2.5 degrees in EE., and I constantly get questions like this - asking how to do something that was just explained - so I try to paraphrase to get the point across. My concern wasn't that the right answer hadn't been provided, but that it wasn't clear, which is what the question said. The point isn't just to answer the question, but to do so in a way that the asker understands the solution. Education is about conveying ideas. If the student(OP) doesn't get it, the teacher (answers on both threads) has failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with the referenced article, but what I would do is:

1. Find the center of the point cloud
2. Use atan2 with the difference between each point and the center to find the angle each makes with the center
3. Sort by angle. You can either store the angle calculated in step 2 with each point (a Z value in a 3d coordinate created from each 2d coordinate is a convenient way to do this) or just skip step 2 and recalculate the angle in your sort comparer
4. Done!

Answer (score 1):

The full quote from that answer is (I added the numbers for easy reference):

1. let `P[0], P[1], ... P[n-1]` be the list of points to sort
2. let M be the barycenter of all points
3. compute `a[0], a[1], ... a[n-1]` such that `a[i] = atan2(P[i].y - M.y, P[i].x - M.x);`
4. sort points relative to their `a` value, using `qsort` for instance.

The "`a` value" part of step 4 is referencing step 3. So, in step 4 it's saying "sort the points array based on the values in the array you made in step 3 (using something like quick sort)."

Now, if sorting that array of values will get you the clockwise order of points, then sorting it in reverse order will give you the points in a counter-/anti-clockwise direction.

Hopefully that clears it up a bit for you.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I'm guessing its because you tried to answer the question.

Comment: @DavidLively I guess we're in the same boat then. :(